# `wc` holding yum lock for over 2 days

Tags: linux, centos, yum, apache2, process

I just logged onto a server that hasn't been logged into for two months (August 2nd). When I did `yum remove google-authenticator`, I got:

```
Existing lock /var/run/yum.pid: another copy is running as pid 31503.
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: wc
    Memory : 524 k RSS (105 MB VSZ)
    Started: Tue Oct  2 07:40:47 2018 - 2 day(s) 9:38:56 ago
    State  : Sleeping, pid: 31503
```

As you can see, `wc` has been holding the `yum` lock for over 2 days. I see it's just the `wc` command being executed in the process with PID 31503:

```
[root@nc0 ~]# ps aux|grep 31503
root      9821  0.0  0.1 112704   924 pts/0    R+   17:21   0:00 grep --color=auto 31503
root     31503  0.0  0.1 107956   524 ?        S    Oct02   0:00 /usr/bin/wc -l
```

Needless to say I'm quite surprised about this. I have two questions:

- How does `wc`, a word (etc.) counter, hold the `yum` lock;
- Why has the `wc` process started running without anyone's intervention...?

Background information: basic server with CentOS 7 and Apache with NextCloud (and PHP).

I checked the `yum.log` and the last update was manual, on August 2nd. `yum-cron` has not been installed.

Comment: Perhaps the cause is that the `yum` process OOM'd on September 5th, and `wc` got the same PID? (`[Wed Sep  5 08:15:07 2018] Killed process 31503 (yum) total-vm:1151456kB, anon-rss:253708kB, file-rss:1448kB, shmem-rss:0kB`)

Comment: Seems plausible. Try a lsof -nPp 31503 just for curiosity, and maybe a ptree too

Comment: Unfortunately, the process was killed by my colleague already, so not much research to do... :(